# Datediff in MsAccess

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, datediff

I am stuck in one place.
I am using DateDiff in Ms Access it is giving me proper output, like

```
StartDate is 10-Sep-2016
EndDate is 15-Oct-2016

Total Days which I will get is 35
& months will i get is 1 Month

DateDiff('d',StartDate,EndDate)
```

**But I want output as 2 months if it is exeeded the 30 days.
  if it is 61 days  then 3 months & so on.

```
**IIFFF days diffrence is 
   29 Days then output should be 1 months
   30 Days then output should be 1 months
   32 Days then output should be 2 months
   60 Days then output should be 2 months
   62 Days then output should be 3 months**
```

Will that be possible in the DateDiff in MsAccess 
or is there any other function available  so that i can achieve the same output.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional logic.  Perhaps something like this:

```
select iif(DateDiff('d', StartDate, EndDate) > 30,
           DateDiff('d',StartDate,EndDate) & " days",
           "2 months"
          )
```

Your logic that anything exceeding 30 days is "2 months" seems strange.  Normally, I think the logic would look like this:

```
select iif(DateDiff('d', StartDate, EndDate) > 30,
           DateDiff('d', StartDate, EndDate) & " days",
           DateDiff('m', StartDate, EndDate) & " months"
          )
```

Comment: Sir, Actually I don't want every time 2 Months, if it is 61 days then I want 3 months so on

Comment: @HardikParmar . . . Hence the second part of the answer.  You may need to add 1 to the months number.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your minimum count of months for a positive count of days is 1, thus:

```
MonthCount = Sgn(DateDiff("d",StartDate,EndDate)) + DateDiff("m",StartDate,EndDate)
```

**Edit**

For a 30-day cut that will produce your example output, use this simple formula in your query:

```
MonthCount: (DateDiff("d",[StartDate],[EndDate])-1)\30+1
```

Answer (score 0):

will this logic suffice to modify your SQL function?

```
Public Function FN_GET_MONTH(iDays As Long, Optional iDaysInMonth As Long = 30)

    If (iDays / iDaysInMonth) > iDays \ iDaysInMonth Then
        FN_GET_MONTH = (iDays \ iDaysInMonth) + 1
    Else
        FN_GET_MONTH = (iDays \ iDaysInMonth)
    End If

End Function

?FN_GET_MONTH(29) = 1
?FN_GET_MONTH(31) = 2
?FN_GET_MONTH(60) = 2
?FN_GET_MONTH(80) = 3
?FN_GET_MONTH(91) = 4
```

you can have this public function and use it in your SQL code like

`FN_GET_MONTH(DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate))`

Comment: Your Answer is the perfect match for me. Your understanding is excetly similar with mine but I am using MS ACCESS database.

Comment: It is for Ms access.. You can use vba public functions within access SQL. @hardik parmar

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to give the results you seek:

```sql
SELECT 
    StartDate,
    EndDate
    numDays,
    ((numDays - 1) \ 30) + 1 AS numMonths
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            StartDate,
            EndDate,
            DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate) AS numDays
        FROM YourTable
    )
```

It gives me

```
numDays  numMonths
-------  ---------
...
     29          1
     30          1
     31          2
     32          2
...
     59          2
     60          2
     61          3
     62          3
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if or a switch statement to check if the output is >0 then show ""01"" otherwise show ""02"".